# Display an error message?

Tags: c

Hi my program basically is when a user input an unrecognizable command it suppose to display an error message, however when the user input valid commands and non valid commands it still displays error message.

```
int main(){

    char command[20];

    printf("Enter either add, sub, mult, div, or EXIT:\n");
    scanf("%5s", command);


    if(strcmp(command, "EXIT") || strcmp(command, "add" ) ||strcmp(command, "sub")|| strcmp(command,"div") || strcmp(command,"mult") != 0){
        printf("Warning either enter the following commands\n");

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Welcome\n");
        //function..
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Also i am new to C and i am experimenting i'm not sure if that is the proper way to implement this feature.

Comment: Any case where your conditions will be false ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing:

```
if (strcmp || strcmp || strcmp || strcmp != 0)
```

You seem to be trying to check ALL the different results against 0 at the same time.

That is not how C works.
You must check each value individually

```
if (strcmp(command, "EXIT") &&
    strcmp(command, "add" ) &&
    strcmp(command, "sub" ) &&
    strcmp(command, "div" ) &&
    strcmp(command, "mult"))
 { /* Show Warning message */ }
```

**Translation:**
If the string is ***not*** `"EXIT"` and also is not `"add"`, and also is not `"sub"`.... then the string was not any known command; Therefore, show a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcmp` function returns `0` if the two strings match. Consequently  your condition will always evaluate as `true`, since only one string can match with a certain input.